# Guava one-liner for transforming immutable lists

Tags: java, guava

I think there must be a one-liner Guava solution for transforming an immutable list into another immutable list, but I can't find it. Suppose we have the following objects:

```
ImmutableList<String> input = ImmutableList.of("a", "b", "c");
Function<String, String> function = new Function<String, String>() {
    @Override
    public String apply(String input) {
        return input + input;
    }
};
```

The transformation can be achieved like this:

```
Iterable<String> transformedIt = Iterables.transform(input, function);
ImmutableList<String> output = ImmutableList.<String>builder().addAll(transformedIt).build();
```

or like this:

```
List<String> transformedList = Lists.transform(input, function);
ImmutableList<String> output2 = ImmutableList.copyOf(transformedList);
```

but I think that there must be somewhere a performance-optimized one-liner for this kind of transformation, without intermediate objects, I just can't find it. Where is it?

Comment: That is possible in java 8 using closures, not sure about Guava.

Comment: @EugenHalca Are there immutable collections in Java 8? (I mean real immutable, not the unmodifiable wrappers). Or if I used Guava ImmutableList with Java 8, would it be possible to transform an ImmutableList into an ImmutableList? Note that transforming into simple lists is done in my question (see the second example), I am asking about transforming into **immutable** lists.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can simply remove your builder and inline it to get a (bit longer) one-liner

```
ImmutableList<String> output =
    ImmutableList.copyOf(Iterables.transform(input, function));
```

This is sort of optimal as the result of `Iterables.transform` is lazy, so no temporary list gets allocated. There are AFAIK some minor inefficiencies:

- Allocation of a `FluentIterable`
- Resizing of the array used for the result

If you really care a lot about the speed, you could benchmark it and compare to something like

```
ArrayList<String> tmp = Lists.newArrayListWithCapacity(input.size());
Iterables.addAll(tmp, Iterables.transform(input, function));
ImmutableList<String> output = ImmutableList.copyOf(tmp);
```

and to a handrolled loop.

## UPDATE

While the first approach is surely the most readable one, it incurs some allocations for array resizing and also the final shrinking to desired size. With a list of length 1234567, there are the following resizing steps:

4 -> 7 -> 11 -> 17 -> 26 -> 40 -> 61 -> 92 -> 139 -> 209 -> 314 -> 472 -> 709 -> 1064 -> 1597 -> 2396 -> 3595 -> 5393 -> 8090 -> 12136 -> 18205 -> 27308 -> 40963 -> 61445 -> 92168 -> 138253 -> 207380 -> 311071 -> 466607 -> 699911 -> 1049867 -> 1574801

and the final shrinking

1574801 -> 1234567

## UPDATE 2

As Louis and Chris said, the optimal solution is

```
ImmutableList<String> output =
    ImmutableList.copyOf(Lists.transform(input, function));
```

as it includes no array copying. This works as the result of `Lists.transform` is a lazy collection and `ImmutableList.copyOf` queries its size in order to allocate a properly sized array. Note that neither `Iterables.transform` nor `FluentIterable` are that efficient.

Comment: Actually, `ImmutableList.copyOf(Lists.transform(input, function))` should completely avoid the resizing of the array.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman: I see. So I could replace my second snippet by this. I guess the OP's point was that there's always some copying, which could be avoided via something like `ImmutableList.copyOfWithCapacity(Iterator, capacity)`. Add the same for an Iterable; two ugly overloads needed.

Comment: @maaartinus My point was that if I ask the question "What is the transform of an ImmutableList?" I think that the intuitive answer is "Another ImmutableList", so there should be somewhere a transform method that does exactly that. It feels unnatural that I have to call ImmutableList.copyOf, and its performance cannot be as good as creating an ImmutableList immediately (altough in my case performance is not critical). I accepted your answer in the sense that "This is missing from Guava, this workaround is the best you can do"

Comment: @user1954847: I fully agree with you. I'd say there should be `FluentIterable.from(input).transform(function).toImmutableList()`.

Comment: @maaartinus, `FluentIterable.from(input).transform(function).toList()` (which returns an `ImmutableList`) exists today. Did you mean something slightly different?

Comment: @user1954847, my benchmarks indicate that `ImmutableList.copyOf(Lists.transform(input, function))` uses minimal intermediate objects. A typical call will allocate four: a `TransformingRandomAccessList`, its iterator, an array, and a `RegularImmutableList`. A smarter `TransformingRandomAccessList` could avoid the iterator allocation, and a special-purpose `ImmutableList`-to-`ImmutableList` `transform` method could avoid the `TransformingRandomAccessList` allocation. But those are small. If you're worried about extra arrays, don't: There aren't any.

Comment: @Chris Povirk: Concerning `FluentIterable.....toList()` you're right; somehow I thought that it returns a mutable list. It could avoid the resizing as the FluentIterable can remember the size and allocate properly sized result, but it doesn't. I guess I'll try a patch.

Comment: @maaartinus, you'll see resizing if you use `Iterables.transform`, but you can avoid it by using `Lists.transform`. I think this was Louis's point up-thread.

Comment: @Chris Povirk: I see I was wrong again (I thought I was debugging your example, but I wasn't). Is there a reason why `Iterables.transform` doesn't try delegate to `Lists`? This would help `FluentIterable`, too.

Comment: @maaartinus, there's an issue filed for this. I've replied there with some more discussion: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1413

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have already written several examples of such one-liners. The transformation is done with minimal creation of new objects. Indeed Guava works in lazy manner: it does not iterate over your list, creates other elements and put it to another list. It creates lazy list that is filled as far as its elements are needed, e.g. while you are iterating over the new list. I think that java 8 with closures will not be too much faster for this use case because it will execute similar byte code but the syntax will be shorter.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose `input.stream().collect(toImmutableList())` is what you need. See [doc](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html#toImmutableList--)